# ionic serve --lab not showing different platform views

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have recently been trying to ionic labs view a try. From the docs, its as simple as the command `ionic serve --lab` . But this only shows the normal `ionic serve` view not android and iphone view . I do not see any errors.

```
$ ionic serve -l

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /home/raj/ionic/bookemon
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--lab" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

[12:10:35]  ionic-app-scripts 1.0.0 
[12:10:35]  watch started ... 
[12:10:35]  build dev started ... 
[12:10:35]  clean started ... 
[12:10:35]  clean finished in 6 ms 
[12:10:35]  copy started ... 
[12:10:35]  transpile started ... 
[12:10:39]  transpile finished in 3.58 s 
[12:10:39]  webpack started ... 
[12:10:39]  copy finished in 3.74 s 
[12:10:46]  webpack finished in 6.89 s 
[12:10:46]  sass started ... 
[12:10:47]  sass finished in 719 ms 
[12:10:47]  build dev finished in 11.23 s 
[12:10:47]  watch ready in 11.31 s 
[12:10:47]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

This is my ionic info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.6
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.2.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Not sure whats going on here. I tried reinstalling `ionic` and `npm_modules` but its not working. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure that you are opening `http://localhost:8101/ionic-lab` and NOT just `http://localhost:8101` ?

1. Run `ionic serve --lab` or `ionic serve -l`
2. Goto `http://localhost:8101/ionic-lab`

**Note**

- `localhost:8101`  loads the normal view and
- `localhost:8101/ionic-lab`  loads the view with options to various platform

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "watch",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "watch"
  }
```

In `package.json` change scripts to above and run `ionic serve -l`

Comment: I have it. But still the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think `ionic serve -l` doesn't work since ionic 2 using 
ionic-app-scripts.

while, them using ionic view app, for live test.

check here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionic.viewapp&hl=en

Comment: do you have any links to verify that?